# writing a ruby regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

How would I write a ruby regexp that checks for this:

no more than 4 characters, any combination of mpls in any order, and each character must not occur more than once. All must be lowercase as well. **The 4 characters are mpls.**

Valid: mpl
Valid: s
Valid: lmps

Invalid: MpLS
Invalid: mmpls

Thank you

Comment: The condition `no more than 4 characters` is redundant since `each [or the four] character[s] must not occur more than once`.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will do it for you if you do not want repeated character.

```
^(?!(.).*\1)[mlps]{1,4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is easier to write a regex that matches invalid strings. And this regex is more efficient than, for example Sabuj Hassan's regex.

```
re = /(.).*\1|[^mpls]/

"mpl" !~ re   # => true
"s" !~ re     # => true
"lmps" !~ re  # => true
"MpLS" !~ re  # => false
"mmpls" !~ re # => false
```